# Undeservedly received badge

Tags: bug, badges

I just received the mortar board badge but only receive 198 rep today.

Not that I'm complaining but is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The badge only calculates positive reputation events for the day. Easy rule to follow: anything that is red (negative) will not be counted when calculating whether or not you hit the 200 mark, as far as the badge goes. The green (positive) events have some additional criteria, such as the association bonus and reversals not contributing to the badge check.

Comment: Ah righty. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Do reversals update for the day(s) they affected? E.g. could I loose a badge in retrospect?

Comment: @Tim Well since downvotes are ignored, reversing them wouldn't actually change that day since they were already ignored to begin with. Unless I'm missing something. An upvote reversal could cause you to *lose* past days, though